# Ripping my hair for 2 hours,Cannot read property push of undefined (mongoose)

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

the problem is occuring when i try to add a comment from //localhost/campgrounds/:id/comments/new to //localhost/campgrounds/comments

hers's my app.js file

```js
var app=require("express")();
var mongoose=require("mongoose");
var bodyparser=require("body-parser");

var campground=require("./models/campgrounds")
var comment=require("./models/comments.js")
var seedDB=require("./seeds")


//part where the problem is occuring


app.get("/campgrounds/:id/comments/new",function(req,res){
    campground.findById(req.params.id,function(err,campground){
        if(err){
            console.log(err)
        }
        else{
            console.log(campground)
            res.render("comments/new",{campground:campground});
        }
    })
    
})
app.post("/campgrounds/:id/comments",function(req,res){
    campground.findById(req.params.id,function(err,comments){
        if(err){
            console.log(err)
            res.redirect("/campgrounds")
        }
        else{
            comment.create(req.body.comment,function(err,comment){
                if(err){
                    console.log(err)
                }
                else{
                    
                        campground.comments.push(comment)
                        campground.save();
                        res.redirect("/campground/"+campground._id)
                    }
                    
                
            })
        }
    })
})
```

here's the comments file

```js
var mongoose=require("mongoose")

var commentSchema=new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        text:String,
        author:String
    });

module.exports=mongoose.model("comments",commentSchema);
```

and the campground(model file)

```js
var mongoose=require("mongoose");

var campgroundSchema= new mongoose.Schema({
    name:String,
    image:String,
    description:String,
    comments:[
        {
            type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref:"comments"
        }]
});

module.exports=mongoose.model("campgrounds",campgroundSchema)
```

the thing confusing me the most is that my seed.js file working fine completely..
Please help or atleast clear ot my doubt here..

heres's the seed.js file

```js
var mongoose=require("mongoose")
var campground=require("./models/campgrounds")
var comment=require("./models/comments")

var data=[
    {
        name:"Monet hill",
        image:"https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1537905569824-f89f14cceb68?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60",
        description:"Love the weather here"
    },
    {
        name:"Picasso point",
        image:"https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1537905569824-f89f14cceb68?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60",
        description:"Awesome view"
    },
    {
        name:"Renoir's pedestal",
        image:"https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1537905569824-f89f14cceb68?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60",
        description:"Scary but exciting"
    }];

function seedDB(){
campground.remove({},function(err){
    if(err){
        console.log(err)
    }
    else{
        console.log("campgrounds cleaned")
        data.forEach(function(seed){
            campground.create(seed,function(err,campground){
                if(err){
                    console.log(err)
                }
                else{
                    console.log("data added")
                    comment.create(
                            {
                                text:"what a place awesome",
                                author:"boomer"
                            },function(err,comment){
                                if(err){
                                    console.log(err)
                                }
                                else{
                                    campground.comments.push(comment)
                                    campground.save();
                                    console.log("new comment added")
                                }
                            })

                }
            })
        })
    }
})



}
module.exports=seedDB;
```

Answer (score -1):

Found the error(in valhalla right now)

```js
app.post("/campgrounds/:id/comments",function(req,res){
    campground.findById(req.params.id,function(err,comments){
        if(err){
            console.log(err)
            res.redirect("/campgrounds")
        }
        else{
            comment.create(req.body.comment,function(err,comment){
                if(err){
                    console.log(err)
                }
                else{
                    
                        campground.comments.push(comment)
                        campground.save();
                        res.redirect("/campground/"+campground._id)
                    }
                    
                
            })
        }
    })
})
```

here in findById line i was using (err,comments) instead of (err,campgrounds)as it clashes with the value campground.comments.push making it undefined, hence was a simple typo error :) ...